# Draw Separate ablines in different ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm attempting to plot some lines based upon coefficients from some lmer model fits to some ggplot facets. I'd like to plot a different line for each facet. What would be the best way of achieving this?

To obtain my fits, I'm using the following approach, as it's a binomial lmer model:

```
model.coefs <- fixef(model)
curve( invlogit( cbind(1, x) %*% model.coefs ), add=TRUE )
```

This is taken from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21024/plot-a-generalised-mixed-effects-model-with-binomial-errors). When saved to a variable, the curve function gives a bunch of x and y co-ordinates that I'd like to plot on my graphs.

I'm able to get it to produce a decent plot using the base R graphing functions, but I'd rather go for ggplot instead. So, rather than do this to get two different plots for two different models, labelled here as modelA and modelB:

```
plot(x, y)
modelA.coefs <- fixef(modelA)
curve( invlogit( cbind(1, x) %*% modelA.coefs ), add=TRUE )

plot(x, y)
modelB.coefs <- fixef(modelB)
curve( invlogit( cbind(1, x) %*% modelB.coefs ), add=TRUE )
```

I'm trying to get it working in ggplot instead.

```
ggplot(dataset)+
aes(x=x, y=y)+
geom_point()+
facet_wrap(~groupingFactor)+
geom_line(subset(dataset, groupFactor=="factorA"), **[would the solution be to feed this line something here?]**)
```

I suspect part of the problem is my trying to mangle together several examples at once (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511990/how-to-create-a-facet-in-ggplot-except-with-different-variables), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570379/adding-stat-smooth-in-to-only-1-facet-in-ggplot2), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903972/can-you-specify-different-geoms-for-different-facets-in-a-ggplot)), but this feels like it should be simple to work out. What is it I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for including code but you should add data as well to make a reproducible example. If you're unsure about how to go about this, here is the [canonical post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on the subject.

Comment: Check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644661/add-a-vertical-line-with-different-intercept-for-each-panel-in-ggplot2